# What is stored in ~/Library/Caches/<my-app-bundle>/Cache.db?

Tags: macos, cocoa, caching

I'm really wondering what is stored in the mentioned path?

A side question: May a developer use this path (at least the folder) to store his own temp data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [...] what is stored [...] ?

Cached responses from webservers.

> [...] use this path [...] ?

The directory is meant to use for application cache files. Get this path using:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* cacheDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: obtaining 'cacheDir' is very useful, thanks! I see non zero Cache.db files even for applications without network functions. Is this file 
 'only' for responses from webservers?

Comment: Are you sure the apps have no network functions? For example, many apps have auto-updating, which will query a webserver for the latest app version.

Comment: Or they might link a library or just load a plugin (InputManagers, I'm looking at you!) that do!  
Any way: try `sqlite3 ~/Library/Caches/<my-app-bundle>/Cache.db .schema` to see what tables are in the database.  
I see three tables with names like `cfurl_cache_response`. I presume that's Apple's URL caching.